# I need the same file duplicated in my svn repository

Tags: svn

I have a simple inheritance hierarchy of py scripts
say `Cat` and `CoolCat` and `FurryCat`. This files must (according to the voices in my head) be put under two different folders in SVN, where the `Cat` module has to be both in `FurryCat`'s dir and the same for `CoolCat`. -> so I have the same file duplicated in the repository.

```
https://svn/.../FurryCat
    /FurryCat.py
    /Cat.py

https://svn.../CoolCat
    /CoolCat.py
    /Cat.py
```

We are all busy humans so we forget to commit the file twice and so it is bad to find out they are out-of-sync so now you have to observe the svn log and so forth. In my experience, merging python code almost always turns out to be a manual merge.

im guessing it's some

```
svn propedit svn:externals ...
```

?

Comment: The appropriate solution would be to keep a single copy and put the base class in the parent directory.

Comment: cant do that. Must reatain that file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down the `svn:externals` path and this is how you make it :
Basically, when you make an external definition, file appears in the two places.
It’s like quantum theory where particle exist in many places at once.

This is the best tutorial I found on this.
http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Short-tutorial-on-svn-propset-for-svnexternals-p.html

What confused me, was the difference of defining, between a folder and a file.

common https://svn/path/to/common_folder

->  Folder ‘common’ created with the files.

coolest_script_ever.py https://svn/deliciouscripts/awesome.py

->  The file gets into the current dir.

Whats the confusion ? for me it was confusing, as I accustomed  to that when using SVN ‘you always check out a folder’.

Generally to get rid of a bad `svn:externals` definition you should do a

```
svn propdel svn:externals .
```

In the work dir.
But better make it work the first time… and revert if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a symlink (or shortcut in Windows) of one file, pointing to the actual file in the other folder, and commit that symlink to SVN.

However, this question is the exact reason for the DRY (don't repeat yourself) programming principle. Your problem is exactly why you should avoid duplicating code unless absolutely necessary. I'm sure there's a way to structure your code so that there is only one file that both classes inherit from, and I would look into that solution. I would consider that the "right way" to solve this problem instead of some kludge to manage the file in both places. That seems like bad practice to me.

Comment: I specifically stated that the file structure is given and cannot be changed. Anyhow this is the practice that is preferred.

Comment: If its given you can use SVN Commit hooks to sync.